# Let $X$ be a connected CW complex and $G$ a group such that every $\pi_1(X)\to G$ is trivial. Show that every $X\to K(G, 1)$ is nullhomotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

Question 2 in Chapter 1.B in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology:

> Let $X$ be a connected CW complex and $G$ a group such that every homomorphism $\pi_1(X)\to G$ is trivial. Show that every map $X\to K(G, 1)$ is nullhomotopic.

Some defintions:

A **$K(G,1)$** space is a path connected spaces whose fundamental group is isomorphic to a given group $G$ and which has a contractible universal covering space.

A map is **nullhomotopic** if is homotopic to the constant map.

A theory I have been thinking of using is Theorem 1B.9 in the text:

Let $X$ be a connected CW complex and let $Y$ be a $K(G,1)$. Then
every homomorphism $\pi_1(X, x_0)\to\pi_1(Y, y_0)$ is induced by a map $(X, x_0)\to(Y, y_0)$
that is unique up to homotopy fixing $x_0$
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Theorem 1B.9 is a good tool here.  In particular, you'll want to use the *uniqueness* part of the theorem.  That means that any two maps $(X,x_0)\to (K(G,1),y_0)$ which induce the same map on $\pi_1$ are homotopic.  What does that tell you about a map $f:(X,x_0)\to (K(G,1),y_0)$ which induces the trivial homomorphism on $\pi_1$?

The answer is hidden below.

> It tells you $f$ is homotopic to the constant map $(X,x_0)\to (K(G,1),y_0)$, since the constant map also induces the trivial homomorphism on $\pi_1$.  So, if there are no nontrivial homomorphisms $\pi_1(X)\to G$, this applies to *every* map $f:X\to Y$ (for an appropriate choice of basepoints $x_0$ and $y_0$).